# Does EOS VC invest in dApps in exchange for equity or tokens?

Tags: dapp

EOS VC has taken forward steps to invest in dApps in partnership with other VCs. In the traditional world, VCs invest in companies in return for equity. What does EOS VC and their partners seek in return for their investment? Is it equity, tokens, both or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short list of potential items:

- Ownership
- Royalties
- Board seats
- Stock/Token Options
- Rights to Intellectual Property
- Influence on choosing strategic partners

---

The VCs will be extracting value in some way, current/future for their limited partners.  If you want more color as to what is possible.  Google term sheets or go watch one of Stanford's lectures on venture capital on YouTube.

---

Here's the info on Block.one's funding that's public:

https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/block-one